# Hardening VM-HOST Set-AdvancedSetting with PowerCLI from csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, vmware, powercli

I would like to automate the configuration of the first HOST to create the Host Profiles with PowerCLI. I built the first HOST in ESXi 6.5 and did the fist Host Profiles from that HOST. But to create the first Host Profiles, I did a Edit Host Profiles line by line and it take so long. We have over 60 diffrents clusters and that means I will have to create one Host Profiles per Cluster.

I did an export from the first Host with PowerCLI with this line

```
Get-AdvancedSetting -Entity $HOST65 | Export-Csv -Path T:\_Evergreening_\Script\$clHOSTprofile-config.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I got this in the csv file (Header)

```
Uid Value   Description Type    Entity  Id  Name    Client
```

I would to use the CSV file for a Set-AdvancedSetting using Name and Value column

```
Get-AdvancedSetting -Entity $HOST65 -Name 'from_csv_file' | Set-AdvancedSetting -Value 'from_csv_file'
```

I'm not sure how to set this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout 'Import-Csv'

You could do something like:

```
# Obtain and export Advanced Settings from a specified host
Get-AdvancedSetting -Entity $HOST65 | Export-Csv -Path T:\_Evergreening_\Script\$clHOSTprofile-config.csv -NoTypeInformation

# Import CSV file into a PowerShell array object
$csvInputs = Import-Csv -Path T:\_Evergreening_\Script\$clHOSTprofile-config.csv

# Create a loop to address each item of the array, sourcedfrom the CSV 
foreach ($csvInput in $csvInputs) {

     # Obtain and set the individual advanced setting on a specified host
     Get-AdvancedSetting -Entity $HOST6502 -Name $csvInput.Name | Set-AdvancedSetting -Value $csvInput.Value

}
```

Comment: Your the king  :-)